# Is Android httppost to https URL using HttpClient secure?

Tags: android, httpclient

I am new bee to android and stack overflow too.

I am developing an android app to the client.In this i want to do an http post users credentials to a https URL using httpclient in android.

I want to know whether that the posted users data is transfered securely over the network to the HTTPS URL.I am not using any self signed certificates or anything,just httpclient

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using HTTPS, yes, it's encrypted. If your app is able to properly verify the server certificate, you can be fairly certain you are sending the data to its intended recipient too.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay for the response. I am not verifying any server certificate.I am just posting data to the HTTPS URL.If i don't verify, is the data prone to Man in the Middle attack?

Comment: If you are posting successfully, that usually means the certificate is automatically verified (unless you installed your own 'trust-all' trust manager). And yes, if you are not verifying the server certificate, you are vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will try posting to the data to the HTTPS URL and let you know

Comment: Sorry Nikolay,One more doubt. In order to verify the server certificate, do i need to have the certificate itself in the keychain of the phone?

Comment: If it is signed by a CA Android trusts, no. If it is self-signed, you will need to.

Comment: Ok nikolay,i will find out from the client about that and will keep you posted on that.

Answer (score 0):

follow this blog. 
http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

HTTPS is not enough as you are vulnerable to MITM attacks